# logstash input eventlog plugin

Tags: logstash, event-log

question about logstash eventlog plugin: to test it I would like to start this way

1- windows machine, go to My COmputer etc, open APplication Event Logs and save on a file, say Application.evtx
2- make logstash read this file and parse it using eventlog input plugin

Is this feasible? to me looks like the eventlog input plugin links directly to where Windows send Application or Systems etc events so it will not be available to parse a local file. ?

Thanks

Franco

Answer (score 0):

To read a local file, use the file{} input.  If you can link the eventlog{} input directly to your events, that would be better/stronger/faster.